# Regular expression for price validation

Tags: regex, validation

Need regular expression which have:

1. Maximum 8 digits before decimal(.) point
2. Maximum 4 digits after decimal point
3. Decimal point is optional

Maximum valid decimal is 8 digits before decimal and 4 digits after decimal 
So 99999999.9999

The regular rexpression I have tried **^\d{0,8}[.]?\d{1,4}$** is failing for 123456789 
and more than this. means it is taking more than 8 digits if decimal point is not available.

Tested here : http://regexpal.com/

Many many thanks in advance!

Comment: Price can't be negative?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
^\d{0,8}(\.\d{1,4})?$
```

You can make the entire decimal optional

Comment: You need to place a backslash before the period (dot): i.e. `(\.\d{1,4})?` otherwise you are accepting ANY character including another digit.

Answer (score 8):

You can try this:

```
^\d{1,8}(?:\.\d{1,4})?$
```

or

```
^[1-9]\d{0,7}(?:\.\d{1,4})?$
```

If you don't want to have a zero as first digit.

You can allow this if you want: (.1234)

```
^[1-9]\d{0,7}(?:\.\d{1,4})?|\.\d{1,4}$
```

Comment: Thank you for your super fast response! I see it is failing for .12345678 It should take only .1234.

Comment: @user2338652 if you expect the value to be max 4 digits after decimal point..you should not accept the input if its greater than 4..that could lead to **rounding** errors..just **dont't** accept the input if it doesnt match your criteria..and **valiadation!=match**

Comment: @user2338652 FYI, the answer you have accepted also "fails" on `.123456789`.

Comment: Hmm :) It was failing but see the answer is modified and a note is added below that.

Comment: @user2338652 Sure, the answer is modified and is now almost identical to the first part of this answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Any of the above did not work for me.
Only this works for me

```
^([0-9]{0,2}((.)[0-9]{0,2}))$
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex is working for most cases even negative prices,

```
(\-?\d+\.?\d{0,2})
```

Tested with the following,

```
9
9.97
37.97
132.97
-125.55
12.2
1000.00
10000.00
100000.00
1000000.00
401395011
```

If there is a price of **$9.97, £9.97 or €9.97** it will validate **9.97** removing the symbol.

Answer (score 0):

**1-**(\$+.*[1-9])

**2-**(\£+.*[1-9])
**You can use this expression for complete price digits.**

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this:

```
^[1-9]\d{0,7}(\.\d{1-4})$
```

**^** = the start of the string

**[1-9]** = at least the string has to begin with 1 number between 1 and 9

**\d{0,7}** = optional or max 7 times d (digit: a number between 0 and 9)

**()** = create a group like a substring

**.** = need a .

**\d{1-4}** = digit repited max 4 time

**$** end of the string

Answer (score 0):

For price validation we can not allow inputs with leading repeating zeros like 0012 etc.

My solution check for any cases. Also it allows maximum 2 decimal point after the dot.

```
^(?:0\.[0-9]{1,2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]*(\.[0-9]{1,2})?|0)$
```

[image: price input regex expression]