# Detect price in text

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to detect price either in words or in numbers. Is there a way to use regex to determine this or something else would work better?

For numbers, the regex I come up with is ^\d{0,8}(.\d{1,4})?$ which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17482526/4397381)

Can price in words be detected using regex, for eg: five hundred fifty one?
I am looking at Grocery invoice, an example is given below, I want to extract the price of each product and the total price. Also I want to know whether the price in words can be extracted using regex?

> XLant Groceries
>
> Item ID AMNIL PARA 101 103
>
> Bill no: 100000000070
>
> Date: 16-May-2012 1:07 AM
>
> No. of items: 4 Amount (Rs.): 415.65,
>
> Qty Units ItemName
>
> 2 No(s) Amul Ice cream - Vanilla - 1 litre pack
>
> 2 Strips) Paracetemol tablets 500mg
>
> 1 No(s) Close up Toothpaste - 200g
>
> 1 No(s) Gillette Mach3 Razor blade
>
> Total
>
> Price (Rs.)
>
> 220.00
>
> 25.00
>
> 70.00
>
> 100.00
>
> 415.00
>
> Total Price in Words : Four hundred fifteen

Comment: Provide an example of your text and what exactly you want to find.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this regexp as [seen here](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-trick-numbers-in-english.html) (PCRE and python compatible):

```
(?x)           # free-spacing mode
(?(DEFINE)
  # Within this DEFINE block, we'll define many subroutines
  # They build on each other like lego until we can define
  # a "big number"

  (?<one_to_9>  
  # The basic regex:
  # one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine
  # We'll use an optimized version:
  # Option 1: four|eight|(?:fiv|(?:ni|o)n)e|t(?:wo|hree)|
  #                                          s(?:ix|even)
  # Option 2:
  (?:f(?:ive|our)|s(?:even|ix)|t(?:hree|wo)|(?:ni|o)ne|eight)
  ) # end one_to_9 definition

  (?<ten_to_19>  
  # The basic regex:
  # ten|eleven|twelve|thirteen|fourteen|fifteen|sixteen|seventeen|
  #                                              eighteen|nineteen
  # We'll use an optimized version:
  # Option 1: twelve|(?:(?:elev|t)e|(?:fif|eigh|nine|(?:thi|fou)r|
  #                                             s(?:ix|even))tee)n
  # Option 2:
  (?:(?:(?:s(?:even|ix)|f(?:our|if)|nine)te|e(?:ighte|lev))en|
                                          t(?:(?:hirte)?en|welve)) 
  ) # end ten_to_19 definition

  (?<two_digit_prefix>
  # The basic regex:
  # twenty|thirty|forty|fifty|sixty|seventy|eighty|ninety
  # We'll use an optimized version:
  # Option 1: (?:fif|six|eigh|nine|(?:tw|sev)en|(?:thi|fo)r)ty
  # Option 2:
  (?:s(?:even|ix)|t(?:hir|wen)|f(?:if|or)|eigh|nine)ty
  ) # end two_digit_prefix definition

  (?<one_to_99>
  (?&two_digit_prefix)(?:[- ](?&one_to_9))?|(?&ten_to_19)|
                                              (?&one_to_9)
  ) # end one_to_99 definition

  (?<one_to_999>
  (?&one_to_9)[ ]hundred(?:[ ](?:and[ ])?(?&one_to_99))?|
                                            (?&one_to_99)
  ) # end one_to_999 definition

  (?<one_to_999_999>
  (?&one_to_999)[ ]thousand(?:[ ](?&one_to_999))?|
                                    (?&one_to_999)
  ) # end one_to_999_999 definition

  (?<one_to_999_999_999>
  (?&one_to_999)[ ]million(?:[ ](?&one_to_999_999))?|
                                   (?&one_to_999_999)
  ) # end one_to_999_999_999 definition

  (?<one_to_999_999_999_999>
  (?&one_to_999)[ ]billion(?:[ ](?&one_to_999_999_999))?|
                                   (?&one_to_999_999_999)
  ) # end one_to_999_999_999_999 definition

  (?<one_to_999_999_999_999_999>
  (?&one_to_999)[ ]trillion(?:[ ](?&one_to_999_999_999_999))?|
                                    (?&one_to_999_999_999_999)
  ) # end one_to_999_999_999_999_999 definition

  (?<bignumber>
  zero|(?&one_to_999_999_999_999_999)
  ) # end bignumber definition

  (?<zero_to_9>
  (?&one_to_9)|zero
  ) # end zero to 9 definition

  (?<decimals>
  point(?:[ ](?&zero_to_9))+
  ) # end decimals definition

) # End DEFINE


####### The Regex Matching Starts Here ########
(?&bignumber)(?:[ ](?&decimals))?

### Other examples of groups we could match ###
#(?&bignumber)
# (?&one_to_99)
# (?&one_to_999)
# (?&one_to_999_999)
# (?&one_to_999_999_999)
# (?&one_to_999_999_999_999)
# (?&one_to_999_999_999_999_999)
```

But that may be overkill :)

Considering the structure of your data, perhaps you could just try to find what's after `Total Price in Words :`

So something like this may work for you:

```
^\h*Total Price in Words\s*:\s*(.*)
```

You'll find the data on the group 1 (usually `$1` or `\1`)

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GXkRvi/1/)

Answer (score -1):

Answer provided using https://regex101.com/codegen?language=python which I recommend.

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"[\d]*"

test_str = "My text with numbers : 324 and 2342 1 3. G00d Luck!"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
    matchNum = matchNum + 1

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

Comment: How is that supposed to match 'numbers in English'?